# Angular request option printing in console but not getting sent in actual request

Tags: angular, rest, post

I have created a multipart/form-data request in Angular 5 like this:

```
    var rqo : RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
      headers : new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization':sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token'),
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      })
    });
    console.log(rqo);
    return this.http
        .post(this.url+ "v2/document/upload/", param, rqo)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

In this code, `console.log` is printing the right headers and I want to send the same headers in the request, but when I check the sent headers inside chrome, then the request headers contain only some default values and not the ones I'm sending.

Can you please point to what I might be doing wrong. Could it be a cache problem. I already tried using `npm install` and then running the project again. Also tried `ng build --aot --output-hashing=all` and then `ng serve` Still didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

---

some extra info - I faced the same problem a few weeks ago, but it automatically disappeared when I ran the project again. But this one is not getting solved with same method.
Also, using the same technique, I'm able to send 15+ other requests in the same project. But all of them are json requests not multipart

Thank You!

Comment: I guess `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',` can be a part of response header only. It is something related to CORS, which has the list of allowed host urls.

Answer (score 0):

how i got this fixed was instead of this header:

```
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization':sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token'),
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
```

I used this header:

```
    'Authorization':sessionStorage.getItem('auth-token'),
    'Accept':'application/json',
```

content type is automatically set to multipart/form-data and it just works